# .aspx model window not showing controls in windows 10 OS, it does show in win 7

Tags: asp.net

We have an legacy web applications written in asp.net. one of the .aspx model page not showing control after page renders completely. we just migrated our machine from win 7 to win 10. in win 7 it still work without any issue however no in win 10. any solution?

[image: aspx model page with no control]

Comment: Could you please edit your question so as to create a [Minimal, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You haven't posted your code. The screenshots looks kind-of-like a frame that points to the wrong URL. WIth so little information it's impossible to help. Don't look for OS differences though. Which browsers have you tested? Does your application run on any modern browser or does it work with only a specific IE version found on Windows 7?

Comment: It's far more likely that your code uses features only available in old IE versions, but people can only gues as long as there's no code, no error messages, no logs

Comment: The web site is working fine in win 7 with IE 10. however not in win 10 IE 11. i used compatibility and also set emulators. did not help much. The site only accessible to IE and not to any other browser.